# VB Clicked Links Open In New Tab

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching around for a while for some code to do this, and I found a couple. most of them didn't work but I'm trying to get this one to work.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    'This creates a new tab
    Dim tp As New TabPage
    TabControl1.Controls.Add(tp)

    'This creates a new webbrowser with the NewWindow Event
    'And navigates it to the link wanting to be opened
    Dim wb As New WebBrowser
    Dim myElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim target As String = myElement.GetAttribute("href")
    With wb
        .Navigate(target)
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End With

    AddHandler wb.NewWindow, AddressOf WebBrowser_NewWindow

    tp.Controls.Add(wb)

    'This prevents ie from popping up
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

But then I get a error on here `WebBrowser_NewWindow`, and when I check and see what it says and I am told `WebBrowser_NewWindow Is Not Declared. It may be inaccessible due to protection level` How am I supposed to fix this?

Full Code

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.BringToFront()
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
    End Sub

    Private Sub IClarityButton2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IClarityButton2.Click
        If TextBox2.Text = "Close" Then
            End
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = "Invalid"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
        'This creates a new tab
        Dim tp As New TabPage
        TabControl1.Controls.Add(tp)

        'This creates a new webbrowser with the NewWindow Event
        'And navigates it to the link wanting to be opened
        Dim wb As New WebBrowser
        Dim myElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
        Dim target As String = myElement.GetAttribute("href")
        With wb
            .Navigate(target)
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        End With

        'AddHandler wb.NewWindow, AddressOf WebBrowser_NewWindow

        tp.Controls.Add(wb)

        'This prevents ie from popping up
        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `WebBrowser_NewWindow` is a handler for adding a new window to wb. Does this `sub` exist in your code? Just remove that entire row if you dont wan't an action to occur when new windows are added

Comment: Is the handler in the same class as the object that fires the event?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `AddHandler wb.NewWindow, AddressOf WebBrowser_NewWindow`

Comment: It doesn't do nothing with the link if I remove it.

Comment: Then you need to ensure that `WebBrowser_NewWindow` exists in your code and that it carries out some task when a new window is added

Comment: But it's in the WebBrowser1.NewWindow sub. Or it's not sopose to be?

Comment: That line of code is telling the programme to run `WebBrowser_NewWindow` when a new `Window` is added to `wb`. If the sub `WebBrowser_NewWindow` doesn't exist as its own standalone routine then you are going to get an error. Maybe you should paste all your code into the question so we can see